# Script needed to copy data to a mounted storage device

Tags: mount, scripts

I have a 1 TB HDD. And have problems copying data to it whenever i update it on my Ubuntu Machine.Can anybody suggest me how to make a script for Ubuntu such that whenever i mount it copy the newly dumped data from my PC HDD to my external HDD?

Comment: you mean *one time* once (after) it is mounted?

Comment: yes i meant the same

Comment: perfect! I am glad it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a script, running in the background, checking every (for example) 20 seconds if the disc is mounted. If it is, it runs an `rsync` job (once) to upload/update the files on the external disc.

The script below is an example, and so is the suggested rsync job. use `man rsync` for more information on rsync. It runs the backup job one single time after it is connected, waiting for the next time the disc is disconnected/connected, or when the script restarted.

#### How to use

- Open the external disc or partition, right-click somewhere in the root directory of the disc and choose "properties" to see where the disc or partition is mounted (In the Location field of the nautilus properties window).
- Copy the script below, paste it into an empty file and set the line:

  ```
  mounted_volume = "/mountpoint/of/the/disc"
  ```
- Set the right paths in the lines:

  ```
  source_dir = "/path/to/source"
  target_dir = "/path/to/destination"
  ```

Save it as `copy_ifconnected.py`, run it by the command (and keep it running in the background):

```
python3 /path/to/copy_ifconnected.py
```

If it does what you want, add it to your startup applications.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import time

mounted_volume = "/mountpoint/of/the/disc"

source_dir = "/path/to/source"
target_dir = "/path/to/destination"

rsync = "rsync -r -t"

curr_status = False

def run_backup():
    rsync_job = rsync+" "+source_dir+" "+target_dir
    subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", rsync_job])

while True:
    connected = subprocess.check_output(["lsblk"]).decode("utf-8")
    test1 = mounted_volume in connected; test2 = curr_status==True
    if test1 != test2:
        if test1 == True:
            run_backup()
            curr_status = True
        else:
            curr_status = False
    time.sleep(20)
```

Comment: Can you also write a bash version for the same?